# Is sstable2json broken in Cassandra 0.6.0-beta3?

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I'm getting `NullPointerException`:s when using `sstable2json` in Cassandra 0.6.0-beta3:

```
$ bin/sstable2json .../cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-1-Data.db
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3357)
    at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3343)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExport.export(SSTableExport.java:255)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExport.export(SSTableExport.java:299)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExport.export(SSTableExport.java:323)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExport.main(SSTableExport.java:367)
```

I've had no problems with `sstable2json` when using Cassandra 0.5.

Is `sstable2json` broken in Cassandra 0.6.0-beta3 or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug is documented in [CASSANDRA-934](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-934) and was fixed in Cassandra 0.6.1.

Answer (score 1):

Please submit bug reports to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA, not SO.

Comment: jbellis: The problem is that I'm not sure it is a bug - therefore my question. The more likely scenario is that it is me invoking sstable2json incorrectly :-) Please let me know if you believe this to be a bug - then I'll JIRA it